# How to do Nesting of html elements in cakePHP 3 syntax?

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I want to know that how to write the below given html code in cakePHP 3 syntax :-

```
<a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply put the span tag inside the html link this way

```
<?= $this->Html->link(
    '<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>',
    '#', [
        'class' => "sidebar-toggle",
        'data-toggle' => "push-menu",
        'role' => "button",
        'escape' => false
    ]); ?>
```

or you can use the `tag` method to create the span tag

```
<?= $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('span', 'Toggle navigation', ['class'=>"sr-only"]),
    '#', [
        'class' => "sidebar-toggle",
        'data-toggle' => "push-menu",
        'role' => "button",
        'escape' => false
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Can u tell me the parameters of the        $this->Html->link(); ?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you are asking... The manual explains [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links) how `link()` works